# Unable to query another port and send back the response to user

Tags: c, sockets

First of all, sorry if my title is not a good one. Couldn't think of a good title.
So, what I tried is I created a application which listens all packets on port 27080. Then, it sends that packets to another port (where there is a server which responds) and then sends back that response to user. Now, with iptables I redirected a specific type of packets (query packets) from main port to this application. Now, since the response is being received by the user, the main server should be in my list online. However, as soon as I start redirecting packets to this app, it isn't.

The code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <string.h> // memset()
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <linux/ip.h> // For ipv4 header.
#include <linux/udp.h> // For udp header.

#define PORT 27080
#define BUFF_LEN 512

void die(char * error);
void QueryServer(char * ServerIP, char * ServerPort, char * Query, int QueryLen, char * Response, int ResponseSize, int *ResponseLen);

int main() {
    // Create a UDP socket.
    int iSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (iSocket == -1) {
        die((char *) "Unable to create socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sock_structure;

    memset((char *) &sock_structure, 0, sizeof(sock_structure)); // Zero out the structure.

    sock_structure.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock_structure.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sock_structure.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Bind socket to port.
    if (bind(iSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_structure, sizeof(sock_structure)) == -1) {
        die((char *) "Error binding to port");
    }

    // Keep listening for data.
    struct sockaddr_in recvsock_structure;
    socklen_t recvsock_len = sizeof(recvsock_structure);

    // Declare variables for send socket.
    int send_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in send_socket_structure;

    int recv_len = 0;
    char recv_data[BUFF_LEN];

    while (true) {
        recv_len = recvfrom(iSocket, recv_data, BUFF_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &recvsock_structure, &recvsock_len);
        if (recv_len == -1) {
            die((char *) "Error recieving data");
        }

        // Query server.
        char send_data[BUFF_LEN];
        int send_data_len;
        QueryServer((char *) "SERVERIP", (char *) "SERVERPORT", recv_data, recv_len, send_data, BUFF_LEN, &send_data_len);
        //printf("Sending response to %s:%d : %s\n", inet_ntoa(recvsock_structure.sin_addr), ntohs(recvsock_structure.sin_port), send_data);
        // Send the response.
        if (sendto(iSocket, send_data, send_data_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &recvsock_structure, recvsock_len) == -1) {
            die((char *) "Error sending response");
        }
/*
        if (recv_len > 4) {
            switch(recv_data[4]) {
                case 'T' : { // Info query, check cache.
                    // Query server.
                    char send_data[BUFF_LEN];
                    int send_data_len;
                    QueryServer((char *) "SERVERIP", (char *) "SERVERPORT", recv_data, recv_len, send_data, BUFF_LEN, &send_data_len);
                    printf("Recieved data : %s\n", send_data);
                    // Send the response.
                    if (sendto(iSocket, send_data, send_data_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &recvsock_structure, recvsock_len) == -1) {
                        die((char *)"Error sending response");
                    }

                    break;
                }
                // Further : not an info query.
                case 'U' : { // PlayerList.
                    break;
                }
                case 'V' : { // Rules
                    break;
                }
                case 'W' : { // GetChallenge
                    break;
                }
                default : { // Other.

                }
            }
        }*/

        //printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(recvsock_structure.sin_addr), ntohs(recvsock_structure.sin_port));
        //printf("Data: %s\n" , recv_data);
    }

    close(iSocket);
}

void QueryServer(char * ServerIP, char * ServerPort, char * Query, int QueryLen, char * Response, int ResponseSize, int *ResponseLen) {
    // Create socket.
    int iSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (iSocket == -1) {
        die((char *) "Unable to create socket");
    }

    // Bind socket to any port.
    struct sockaddr_in sock_structure;
    sock_structure.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock_structure.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sock_structure.sin_port = htons(0);

    socklen_t sock_structure_len = sizeof(sock_structure);
    if (bind(iSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_structure, sock_structure_len) == -1) {
        die((char *) "Error binding to port");
    }

    // Query server.
    struct hostent * host;
    host = gethostbyname(ServerIP); // Get server ip address.

    struct sockaddr_in send_sock_structure;
    send_sock_structure.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
    memcpy((char *) &send_sock_structure.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    send_sock_structure.sin_port = htons(atoi(ServerPort));

    if (sendto(iSocket, Query, QueryLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &send_sock_structure, sizeof(send_sock_structure)) == -1) {
        die((char *) "Error sending data to remote server");
    }

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 3;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    setsockopt(iSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (struct timeval *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

    (*ResponseLen) = recvfrom(iSocket, Response, ResponseSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_structure, &sock_structure_len);
    if (*ResponseLen == -1) {
        die((char *) "Error recieving data");
    }

    //printf("%s\n", Response);


    close(iSocket);
}

void die(char * error) {
    perror(error);
    exit(1);
}
```

Could anyone please point me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? This is straight-up C (except for the unused `<string>` include).

Comment: I kind of read many sources and made up the code. I wrote it in .cpp, so thought it should me tagged c++. Didn't knew the sources I read were of 'C'.
A side question : Is there some other way to do it in c++ ?

Comment: *Many* of the things you do would look quite different in modern C++, but rewriting your code is out of scope here, nor is it really relevant to your actual question. I was simply wondering about the tag since your code led me to believe you had incorrectly tagged it as "C++" whereas you intended "C". That's all.

Comment: Could you please check the code and tell what might I be doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tried using wireshark to see if your traffic is going where you expect it to? If fact if what you're trying to achieve is monitoring the traffic libpcap would be an easier option than capturing and forwarding the packets

Comment: Can you show the exact iptables rules you are using?

Comment: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 27016 -m string --algo kmp --string 'TSource 
Engine Query' -j REDIRECT --to-port 27080

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm not trying to monitor traffic. As you can see, there are few printf's which are guaranteeing that data is being received on the port. Also, the UDP traffic which I send to that port (27016 in my case) from which data is being redirected are from my Counter Strike 1.6. It is installed on my CS1.6 server and then I transfer packets from port 27016 (only query packets) to port 27080. The server, however, doesn't shows up.

Comment: Also, regarding this code being if C, I learnt how to do at : "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/" which says C++